# SQL 2008 R2 <null> values transposed to zero value with SQLAzureMW (bcp.exe)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure, azure-sql-database

This is an update of a previous thread that had a SQL Query that was showing anomalies.

It was discovered that when using the open source utility SQLAzureMW to check for compatibility and publish a db to Azure, some null values were being transposed to a zero ('0') value.  This is apparently a default setting in the bcp.exe utility. To override this you can use the -k parameter.

Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187887.aspx

Comment: The most likely reasons would be that the table contents are different on the two systems.  Can you check that the data is the same?

Comment: Thanks Gordon - appreciate your comment. Unfortunately the data is consistent and I have dropped and republished as I investigate with trivial data.  Very frustrating.

Comment: The next question would be whether collations are the same (if you are doing equality comparisons on strings).  Or, if you are doing equality comparisons on floating point types, there could be a subtle difference.  However, I would expect SQL that works on one system to work on the other, if it works.  Otherwise, I would expect an error that some feature is not supported.

Comment: Agree, and that is why I use SQLAzureMW to check compat when uploading. I have discovered a little more info ...

Comment: @Gordon - Thanks for your comments. I went back and reviewed atomically the data. In fact the Azure version has a zero'd entry where a NULL exists on the 2008 version. I'm not sure how this is happening (either SqlAzureMW or a calculated column that references that entry) but at least I know it isn't the SQL query itself.

Comment: . . You and a lot of people who use and develop Azure will be relieved that it is not the query.